# How can i make my app the only app that can run on a specific phone?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, automation, administrator

It's about industrial automation. We want to provide users android phones on which they can only use our own Mobile App Nothing else!

I hope, it's an interesting topic to debate on. Please mention if there is any way to implement this.

PS: We can utilise old versions of Android as well :)

Comment: Have you heard about parental controls? https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en

Comment: I think this is more relevant: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices